# Bypassing SSL certificate in Mechanize

Tags: python, ssl, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm trying to Automate logins to the hardware web interface that we have on Site.
The hardware has a url like this: `https://192.168.100.207/login.shtm`.
This url has an invalid certificate and the browsers will warn me about a possible "Man in the Middle" situation.

So, I'm trying mechanize to automate the login, form filling and submitting changes. The problem ocuurs here:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open('https://192.168.100.207/login.shtm')
```

I get this error

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:1408F081:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:block cipher pad is wrong>
```

I'v looked around for a way to bypass SSl certificate check in mechanize, but found nothing.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: The error message does not look like a certificate verification error, so disabling it will probably not help.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If the block cipher pad is wrong while checking the certificate, why not just skip the whole certificate checking? Thanks for your comment

Comment: Why do you assume that the block cipher bad is wrong *while* checking the certificate? I would rather say that this SSL connection is bad, with our without certificate checking.

Comment: Chrome,IE,Firefox state that the publisher of this certificate is unknown. That's why assumed that the certificate is the problem.

Comment: It might be related to the underlying SSL implementation. None of these browsers use OpenSSL which is used by python. There are several hits when looking for this error message - all with products using OpenSSL (python, ruby, apache...)